# Match the inverse of an expression using RegEx

Tags: regex, vba

I have a list of "tags" (essentially variables) that are defined by letters and/or numerals separated by underscores. I want to pull all of the these tags out from expressions that they're used in, so looking to use RegEx to find and replace the bits in between with a comma.

Example data:

```
(PRRawWater_LevelPV >= 35) AND(PRRawWater_LevelPV_bob <= 100)
MaintOview_Refrig
Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_10 = 0
getAlarmDesc("Refrig", Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_10)
Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_09 = 0
getAlarmDesc("Refrig", Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_09)
Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_08 = 0
getAlarmDesc("Refrig", Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_08)
```

I can pull out the tags themselves using `[\w_]+[_][\w_]+`, however I need to find the inverse of this and I'm not sure how... I've found other examples here but can't get them to work :/

I.e. I need to find from left to right, top to bottom:

`(`

`>= 35) AND(`

`<= 100)\r\n` (where \r\n = carriage return line feed)

etc..

Screenshot from RegExr.com showing the found "tags" - I want to keep these:

[image]

The result I'm after, using VBA to replace the found items with a comma is:

```
,PRRawWater_LevelPV,PRRawWater_LevelPV_bob,
MaintOview_Refrig,
Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_10,
,Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_10,
Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_09,
,Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_09,
Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_08,
,Maint_Refrig_AlarmStr_08,
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it turns out I can match the items I want with VBA without having to replace the text, using the Execute function. Obviously I'm new to regex VBA...

```
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim obj As MatchCollection
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "[\w_]+[_][\w_]+"
End With

For Each cell In Range(Range("E2"), Range("E1").End(xlDown))
    txt = cell.Value

    If regEx.Test(txt) Then
        Set obj = regEx.Execute(txt)
        For i = 0 To obj.Count - 1
            Debug.Print obj.Item(i)
        Next
    End If
Next
```